# Can't apply Geo queries in parse (Parse Framework)

Tags: parse-platform

I have tried to apply the geopoints in parse but I can't do the query. The code is as follows.

```
ParseObject placeObject = new ParseObject("placeObject");
ParseGeoPoint userLocation = (ParseGeoPoint) placeObject.get("location");

ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("PlaceObject");
query.whereNear("location", userLocation);
query.setLimit(10);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> Locaciones, ParseException e) {

        if (e == null) {

            Log.d("ERROR",Locaciones.toString());
            // object will be your game score
        } else {
            Log.d("ERROR",e.toString());
            // something went wrong
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Those first two lines will create a new empty "placeObject" class instance, and read a null "location" property from it and store it in `userLocation`. As a result your query is saying "get me the 10 nearest records to no-where".

Comment: can you once try changing your first line to ParseObject placeObject = new ParseObject("PlaceObject");

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ParseObject.registerSubclass(MasterEntity.class);
    ParseGeoPoint userLocation = new ParseGeoPoint(latitude,longitude);
    ParseQuery<MasterEntity> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserMaster");
    query.whereNear("location", userLocation);
    query.setLimit(30); 
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<MasterEntity>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<MasterEntity> mlist, ParseException e) {
            dlg.dismiss();
            if (e==null) {


            for (int i = 0; i < mlist.size(); i++) {
                MasterEntity cc =  mlist.get(i);

                String s_email = cc.getEmail();
                String s_uname = cc.getuserName();
                String s_objid = cc.getObjectID();
                List<ParseObject> aryFollower = cc.getFollowers();
                List<ParseObject> aryFollowing = cc.getFollowing();


            }

            }
            else
            {
                 Alert.alertOneBtn(getActivity(),"Something went wrong.Please try again later");
            }
        }
    });
```

Sample App : https://github.com/ParsePlatform/AnyWall/tree/master/AnyWall-android

Tutorial :  https://parse.com/tutorials/anywall-android